# Show that $\sum^\limits{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n-\sqrt n}{n^{2}+5n}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Show that $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n-\sqrt n}{n^{2}+5n} \ \text{ diverges.}$$

I have tried Root test, Ratio Test, Cauchy condensation Test but all have failed. I think this has to be done by Comparison Test or Limit Comparison Test. But what is the suitable form it has to be reduced to?

Comment: Limit Comparison is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\dfrac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n^2+5n} \sim \dfrac1n$$
Conclude using limit comparison test.

---

**EDIT** Updated on the request of OP

$$\dfrac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n^2+5n} = \dfrac{1-1/\sqrt{n}}{n+5} = \dfrac1n \underbrace{\left(\dfrac{1-1/\sqrt{n}}{1+5/n}\right)}_{\to 1 \text{ as } n \to \infty}$$

Comment: $$\dfrac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n^2+5n} \sim \dfrac1n$$. Can you elaborate please? How did you reduce it to $1/n$?

Comment: @Martin Done ${}$

Comment: But Limit Comparison Test says that if the limit of the whole thing is positive, then only we can conclude that both the series are either convergent or divergent. Here the limit of whole thing is 0. Can you explain? I might be wrong or missing something

Comment: Compare this term with the series whose $n^{th}$ term is $1/n$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for spoonfeeding

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do in this way:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n-\sqrt n}{n^{2}+5n} > \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n-\sqrt n}{n^{2}-n \sqrt n} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: But is it really greater?